# android inapp billing: how to save purchased items

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, save, in-app-billing

the following code is my inapp billing application but I have a question that how can I save the user purchased items to not need to connect to google play every time the check it?

the following code is my inapp billing application but I have a question that how can I save the user purchased items to not need to connect to google play every time the check it?

```
package com.example.inapptest;

import com.example.inapptest.R;

import com.example.android.trivialdrivesample.util.IabHelper;
import com.example.android.trivialdrivesample.util.IabResult;
import com.example.android.trivialdrivesample.util.Inventory;
import com.example.android.trivialdrivesample.util.Purchase;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ImageView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

boolean mIsPremium = false;
static final String SKU_PREMIUM = "premium";
static final int RC_REQUEST = 10001;
IabHelper mHelper;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    String base64EncodedPublicKey = "MIHNMA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBAQUAA4G7ADCBtwKBrwDEYf1TFjO6qpCR5t/7w+P0luTLEKH6aSUYyXt95mHdJOf7gLoLMYJLlfHp/nVyDLLDIoG5a2RaFE5cwZxc0CCVXouuhkO/B/ckFb03FZcg8T0oOSLIyNiPrrrtlln7DyXhvv60KFk8qozuX46MiR+SZfNdg5AJrV9KDHZ9aIHyHztQkpajZ9WJd7F4theRGom3Gydp0LRTumHcmgweOj0ZF6CzzSEQkgOp7S1Guo8CAwEAAQ==";

    mHelper = new IabHelper(this, base64EncodedPublicKey);
    mHelper.startSetup(new IabHelper.OnIabSetupFinishedListener() {
        public void onIabSetupFinished(IabResult result) {
        mHelper.queryInventoryAsync(mGotInventoryListener);
        }
    });

}

IabHelper.QueryInventoryFinishedListener mGotInventoryListener = new IabHelper.QueryInventoryFinishedListener() {
    public void onQueryInventoryFinished(IabResult result, Inventory inventory) {

        // Do we have the premium upgrade?
        Purchase premiumPurchase = inventory.getPurchase(SKU_PREMIUM);
        mIsPremium = (premiumPurchase != null && verifyDeveloperPayload(premiumPurchase));


        updateUi();
         }




};

public void onUpgradeAppButtonClicked(View arg0) {
      String payload = ""; 

    mHelper.launchPurchaseFlow(this, SKU_PREMIUM, RC_REQUEST, 
            mPurchaseFinishedListener, payload);
}

 // Callback for when a purchase is finished
IabHelper.OnIabPurchaseFinishedListener mPurchaseFinishedListener = new IabHelper.OnIabPurchaseFinishedListener() {
    public void onIabPurchaseFinished(IabResult result, Purchase purchase) {

         if (purchase.getSku().equals(SKU_PREMIUM)) {
            // bought the premium upgrade!
            mIsPremium = true;
            updateUi();
        }

    }
};

 boolean verifyDeveloperPayload(Purchase p) {
     String payload = p.getDeveloperPayload();
     return false;
}



@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    if (mHelper != null) mHelper.dispose();
    mHelper = null;
}

public void updateUi() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    ((ImageView)findViewById(R.id.free_or_premium)).setImageResource(R.drawable.premium);
    findViewById(R.id.upgrade_button).setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

} 
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you use the latest Version 3 of IAB library, then you don't need to save purchases. You can query them from the service every time your application starts, because Google Play service caches the purchases on the device for you. See this [remark on Local Caching](http://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/api.html#caching).